# Apache | Django: How to run websites on the back of a base URL?

Tags: django, apache, hosting, web-hosting

I've got a base url. http://baseurl.com/
I'm trying to run projects on the back of it. For example
http://baseurl.com/mongoose/
The projects run but the URL don't work properly because they all
reference the base url. So for 'About Me' page it points to
http://baseurl.com/about instead of http://baseurl.com/mongoose/about

Is this something i need to change in django or apache? Is what I'm
trying to do even possible?

Coming from an IIS .net background I know that in IIS you can "Create and application" within a site which essentially does what I'm trying to achieve now with Apache and Django.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do anything. Apache is supposed to be setting a request header called `SCRIPT_NAME`, which is your base URL, and all URL reversing takes that into account.

How are you creating these URLs in your templates?

**Update**

So your problem is with getting the URLs of Flatpages. The issue is that the normal way of calculating URLs dynamically, so that they do take `SCRIPT_NAME` into account - using the `reverse()` function or the `{% url %}` tag - doesn't work with Flatpages, because they are not dispatched via urls.py but via a custom middleware which fires on a 404.

So instead of using that middleware, I would use the urls.py mechanism to dispatch to flatpages. Remove the flatpagemiddleware from your settings.py, and in urls.py *at the end of your patterns* add this:

```
url(r'^(?P<url>.*)$', 'django.contrib.flatpages.views.flatpage', name='flatpage'),
```

Now, in your templates, you can do:

```
<a href="{% url flatpage page.url %}">
```

and it should work correctly.

Comment: add to respond by adding an answer. The code wasn't happy being posted in reply to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check any `urls.py` in the project(s) to see if they expect to be top-level. But if the application outputs links like `/something` then it's going to mean the root directory. The application should be reversing a view/parameter into a URL, which would allow you to move it around. If you wrote the apps, check out `reverse` in `django.core.urlresolvers`

Comment: I'm using 'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
so i'm not catching the flatpage urls in my urls.py